# Pyinstaller exe file failed to execute script due to unhandled exception

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

im trying to turn my python program into an .exe file with the command pysintaller --onefile [name], everything goes perfectly but then when i run my .exe file i get the error " failed to execute script due to unhandled exception, No module name requests. I have already installed the libraries and moved my folder out of the dist file , but same thing. Can anyone help me please?(i tested my code with Visual studio it works.[image]

[image]

```
import requests
import tkinter 
from cProfile import label
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def show_data():
    link = ent.get()
    result = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    images = soup.find_all('img')
    liste = []
    for image in images:
        image = image['src']
        if "https://cdn2.sorsware.com" and "buyuk" in image:
              liste.append(image)
    txt.insert(0.0,liste)
def delete_data():
    txt.delete(1.0,END)
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("1000x500")
gui.title("BSL")

l1 = Label(gui,text="Link:")

ent = Entry(gui,width=600)

l1.grid(row=0)
ent.grid(row=0,column=1)
txt = Text(gui,width=125,wrap=WORD,font=("Arial",10))
txt.place(x=500,y=250,anchor=CENTER)
btn = Button(gui,text = "Results",bg ="black",fg="white",width=5,height=2,command=show_data)
btn.grid(row=1)

btn_delete = Button(gui,text = "delete",bg ="black",fg="white",width=5,height=2,command=delete_data)
btn_delete.grid(row=2)
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: It will be difficult to help without more information. Can you post the `pyinstaller` command used and possibly the contents of `alp.py` and `alp.spec`?

Comment: I just did, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Same error for me as well. I have all the dependencies installed but shows "[17180] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!". Tried all the available solutions on net but hard luck :(

Answer (score 1):

pip install requests
try this command once I also got the same error some days before

Comment: i already installed requests sadly it doesnt work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find the `requests` module. Make sure you're running `pyinstaller` in the virtual environment with all dependencies installed.

You can install with

```
pip install requests
```

---

Edited after testing:

I was able to install and execute the `alp.py` script you provided, and build an exe using `pyinstaller`. Here's the steps I followed (on Windows 10).

The directory tree looks like this:

```
alp/
  env/
  alp.py
```

In your `alp` folder, first we'll setup a virtualenv and update it:

```
py -m venv env
source env/Scripts/activate
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If you're using a standard Windows console, you may have to just do `env/Scripts/activate` (omit the `source`) to enable your virtualenv.

Now install dependencies and test the application:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 requests pyinstaller
python alp.py
```

If all goes well, the window opens and there are no errors. Now we can build the executable.

```
pyinstaller --onefile alp.py
```

I suspect that what's happened is when you're running the `pyinstaller` command, you're not in the same virtualenv as the project dependencies, which is why it's unable to import `requests` no matter how many times you reinstall it.

If you're sure you're in the same environment as the dependencies we'll have to see some error output from the `pyinstaller` command perhaps.

Comment: i have already uninstalled and installed most versions of requests and the same error still happens, apparently some people are effected by this issue with the exact same error too

Comment: Did you install dependencies in a virtualenv? Are you running `pyinstaller` from within the same virtualenv?